# Mac (Yosemite) Samba 4.1.6 under Ubuntu

Tags: samba4, osx-yosemite

I'm finding that accessing a Samba share (4.1.6) from a Mac running Yosemite can be extremely slow.  It can take several minutes (no exaggeration) to display a folder containing four or five files.

I've run Wireshark during one of these long pauses and I can see a steady stream of "Create Request File" / "Create Response File" SMB2 packets being sent - referring to a metadata file for each file in a folder that I opened and closed some time ago (i.e. of the form "._Realname" - I believe these are [resource forks](http://offshootinc.com/blog/2007/05/17/say-goodbye-to-ds_store-files-resource-forks-and-thumbsdb-files-on-your-windowsmac-network/)).  There are a few hundred files in this folder so it takes a long time for it to work through them all, during which time other folder access appears to be blocked.

I've tried a couple of things:

- Preventing .DS_Store and resource forks being created:
  Adding a [veto for ._ file creation](http://www.e-rave.nl/disable-creation-of-ds_store-files-on-samba-shares) doesn't help - I can still see it going through the files (and I understand this can cause other problems when you try to copy a folder from somewhere with various dot-underscore files onto the share).
- Connect via port and IP address:
  I've read that connecting via the IP and specifying port 139 directly can have an effect.  This does improve things a little, although I can still see a stream of the "Create Request File" / "Create Response File" packets.

Assuming this is the cause of the slowness, is there a way of preventing Yosemite from even trying to create or read these files for a network share?  (Not just the .DS_Store, but the resource forks as well.)  Is there some magical Samba or Mac configuration option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to inform you, but MacOSX SMB/CIFS went for a ball of sluggy tackiness since Maverick. Sorry, but I've moved to NFS for my home network. Yosemite appeared to be better, but the performance just isn't there with their current SMB/CIFS network stack.
Examples and complaints:
http://www.macwindows.com/Does-the-final-Mavericks-update-fix-SMB-file-sharing.html
http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-file-sharing-smb-super-slow/

It is quite comical that I could copy files from the exact same folder (NAS4Free server) using the MacOSX host and a VM (Windows 7) inside that host, and the VM (VMware and Parallels) does it faster than the host could :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use netatalk which shares folders via afp://
U can use users from /etc/passwd (user1,user2)

```
;
; Netatalk 3.x configuration file
;

[Global]
; Global server settings
server name = NAS
log file = /var/log/netatalk.log
uam list = uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so
mimic model = iPad

[TimeMachine]
path = /share/TimeMachine
valid users = user1,user2
rwlist = user1,user2
time machine = yes

[User1]
path = /share/user1
valid users = user1,user2
rwlist = user1,user2
```

afp has better speed in network with MacOS X

Samba has lower speed.